# How to display Jira dashboard inside iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe, jira

We have a requirement of displaying Jira dash board inside an iFrame but when I am giving my JIRA url and putting up in browser it gives following result in browser console.
"Refused to display 'https://eteaming.worldshop.eu/jira/login.jsp' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"." . Please help me out if you have any solution to it.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Has anything changed since you posted? I am able to visit the mentioned site successfully. https://c.flm.pw/2019-08/Zbfzm.png

Comment: @AustenHolland - thanks for the update . Still I am not able to do that ,It would very kind if you share what you did.

Comment: My apologies, I had thought your link provided was the page that contained the iFrame. By the looks of it, this is not possible with jira. There is an ongoing discussion about it at the jira server bug tracker, here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-20988